# Application Navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been asked to create an application that would serve as an Employment Application for the company I work with.  But I can not seem to figure out any way to set up navigation.  The application is about 4 steps long and each step is on a separate page.  The user should be able to go back to pages they have completed but not forward (in this navigation, advancement is taken care of else where)

I've tried using List items, and hyper links to no avail.  The application pages have a master page, and the master page has a current step property that is set in the page load of each of the steps of the application.

My first thought was to have the set method of the property enable or disable the links but that came up with Null References.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [ASP.NET 2.0 Wizard control](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/standard/wizard.aspx)? All of this is in there for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was told not to use a wizard control and to have each step as its own page, with a master page.

Comment: The person requesting the application has something against them.